# eclipse : impossible to import git project

Tags: linux, eclipse, git, debian, egit

I got a problem with my eclipse, on debian.
When I try to import a git project from github, using egit I got a
    Couldn't create temporary repository.

error after having set my project properties.

However, I works ok when using running eclipse with sudo.

I think it would be related to wrong permissions somewhere, but cannot figure out where :s

I would appreciate some help.

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the [source of `org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.SourceBranchPage.java`](http://repo.or.cz/w/egit.git/blame/dfbdc456d8645fc0c310b5e15cf8d25d8ff7f84b:/org.eclipse.egit.ui/src/org/eclipse/egit/ui/internal/clone/SourceBranchPage.java#l232) mentions `/tmp`, it should be related with some permission issue around `/tmp`.

```
try {
  final URIish uri = newRepoSelection.getURI();
  final Repository db = new Repository(new File("/tmp"));
  listRemoteOp = new ListRemoteOperation(db, uri);
  getContainer().run(true, true, listRemoteOp);
} catch (IOException e) {
  transportError(UIText.SourceBranchPage_cannotCreateTemp);
  return;
}
```

---

The [OP jlengrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282677/jlengrand) actually reports in the comments:

> The problem was simple in fact, but quite handy to track down:
>   My `.gitconfig` file had been corrupted during my debian upgrade, which caused egit to crash.

Comment: Humpph, kinda weird however, as a ls -l give me : drwxrwxrwt   9 root root  4096 Nov 20 18:17 tmp/. I should have all rights needed .

Comment: Ok finally, your mention got me on the right path. The problem was simple in fact, but quite handy to track down :s. My .gitconfig file had been corrupted during my debian upgrade, which caused egit to crash. Thanks for the tip Von C ;)

Comment: @jlengrand: glad you found the cause of this issue. I have included it in the answer, for more visibility.